# jQuery toggle onclick on parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I hide the content of `.ab-content` if I click on `.ab-head`? Also hide when I click on `ab-head` and the `content` is visible. With the code I have right now, it almost works but when I click one of them **all the content is toggled**.

How can I maintain the function only on the `parent div`? Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ab-head").click(function(){
        $(".ab-content").toggle();
    });
    $(".ab-content").click(function(){
        $(".ab-content").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="ab-container">
    <div class="ab-head">
        <h1>some name 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ab-content">
        <p>some text bla bla bla 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ab-container">
    <div class="ab-head">
        <h1>some name 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ab-content">
        <p>some text bla bla bla 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/yppn4nex/

Answer (score 3):

Just toggle the next instance of `.ab-content`:

```
$(".ab-head").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".ab-content").toggle();
});
```

You can also reference the current `<div class="ab-content">` that the user has clicked on using the `this` keyword:

```
$(".ab-content").click(function(){
  $(this).toggle();
});
```

Although if you are wanting to hide the content when you click on it, it's probably better to do something along the lines of what itsgoingdown suggests.

**Quick demo:**

```js
$(".ab-container").on("click", function(){
  $(this).find(".ab-content").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ab-container">
  <div class="ab-head">
    <h1>some name 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ab-content">
    <p>some text bla bla bla 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ab-container">
  <div class="ab-head">
    <h1>some name 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ab-content">
    <p>some text bla bla bla 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this with event delegation:
 Check the **below snippet**

```js
$('.ab-container').on('click', '.ab-content ,.ab-head', function() {

  $(this).closest('.ab-container').find('.ab-content').toggle();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ab-container">
  <div class="ab-head">
    <h1>some name 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ab-content">
    <p>some text bla bla bla 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ab-container">
  <div class="ab-head">
    <h1>some name 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ab-content">
    <p>some text bla bla bla 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```